# Force div not to expand

Tags: css, html

I have a div set to a width of `60%`. I want to have another div of significantly larger width (much of which will not be displayed) nested in it. However, whenever I have the child div increase its size beyond that of the parent, the parent expands to the larger size, even though its `overflow-x` is set to `hidden`. What can I do to fix this?

```
#parent{
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    max-width:60%;
    width:60%;
    display:table-cell;
    border-radius:5px;
    background:#444;
    border-width:10px;
    color:lightgray;
    height:100%;
    padding:1em;
    vertical-align:top;
}
#child{
    width:2000px;
    height:100%;
}
```

## Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/kgsD7/

Comment: do you mean `overflow-x` ? please show your codes .

Comment: yes. Currently adding my css.

Comment: This might be helpful: [Div overflow with display table-cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233959/div-overflow-with-display-table-cell)

Comment: I set the max width in pixels, as @jdero suggested, which worked I think.

Comment: What is the expected result supposed to be? do you want it to scroll? hide?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the `display:table-cell;`

Remove that and the fixed width will work.

Comment: If I do this, the layout in which the parent is a part gets screwed up.

Comment: find a different way. display table and tablecell should be used with care. You can not force it to have a fixed width. Can you post a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Put  table-layout:fixed instead of display:table-cell

Comment: This also messes everything up.

Comment: A fiddle or link would help as the answer you need, needs to work with your complete layout